# Modifying the behaviour of Corda service object at runtime

Tags: corda

Is it possible to update/modify methods(behaviour) of Corda service object(singleton) at run time? For example:

There is a function in the Corda Service object as shown below, which tracks for vault updates, does some processing with the state data and then makes an API call to the external system. At some point the logic of processing the state data may change and would like to modify the behaviour at run time without restarting my corda node.

Is Corda Service right way to do it?
Can Java instrumentation API or Java Assist or any other bytecode re-writing tools may help?

```
private fun trackVaultAndUpdateExternalSystem() {
val ourIdentity = ourIdentity()
serviceHub.vaultService.trackBy<State>().updates.subscribe { update: Vault.Update<State> ->
    update.produced.forEach { message: StateAndRef<State> ->
        val state = message.state.data
        if (state.recipient == ourIdentity) {
            // do some processing and then make an API call to the external system
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to change it at runtime?

Comment: By run time i meant without stopping the corda node, then updating the corda service object and restarting the node back. something like dynamically updating the logic without restarting the corda node. I guess there can be only one instance of the service object throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using the JDWP but I do not recommend this at all. Corda is designed to tolerate downtime. You will not lose messages or cause errors to be observed by counterparties if your node goes offline for a while. If your app cannot tolerate even a few seconds of downtime then you'd need app hotswap but we don't formally support this today.

Comment: got it, thanks. I guess the ideal approach for now would be to build a Fault-tolerant client Observer which has the above function. That would require running replicas of observer configured as master-slave cluster with master being responsible for actually executing the above function and in the event of master failure some other replicas would take over. I am not sure if ZK would be the right tool for it or etcd/raft or K8s would be a better choice in terms of development/maintenance. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the intent here to have an HA RPC client? If so, we know we need to do some more work to enable this - it's something we've been discussing a lot in the last few weeks.

Comment: yeah, the intention is having a HA RPC client.

Comment: Yeah that's unfortunately on us. When do you need it by?

Comment: Not really an urgency right now. It would be nice to have the design/architecture open sourced R3 is planning for this